# Email Verification is not working in flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm following a flutter firebase tutorial, and now i'm trying to verify my signing using Email , the problem is that it does not seem to work , and when i try to verify again , it gives me an FirebaseauthException cause i'm trying too much (as the exception said) to verify the email , which may be weird to FireBase , but why isn't working in the first time,
here is the code , i've tried to print some thing after the line that should send the request to verify , and it worked! :

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => MyState();
}

class MyState extends State<Test> {
  UserCredential? usercredential;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test")),
      body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            try {
              usercredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                      email: 'hamzafz888@gmail.com',
                      password: "verysecretpassword!");
              print("Signed in with temporary account.");
            } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
              if (e.code == 'user-not-found') print("no user in this email");
              if (e.code == 'wrong-password') print("wrong password inserted");
            } catch (e) {
              print("UNKOWN ERROR");
            }
           // print(usercredential!.user!.emailVerified);
            if (!usercredential!.user!.emailVerified) {
              User? user1 = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
              await user1!.sendEmailVerification();
              //print("hello");
            }
          },
          child: Text("Sign In"),
        ))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "is not working" and "does not seem to work" are really hard to help with. When you run this code, what happens - and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: the email that i'm using which is mine should get a verification message , which contains a link , when i click on it , my signing should be verified ( that's what happens with the tutor).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your expected steps. Which is the first of these steps that does not happen?

Comment: i'm not getting the email to verify , and when i try multiple times at the same time , i get a familiar Exception that looks like this  ( FireBaseAuth Exception [ too many requests]....)

Comment: If you don't get an error from the call `sendEmailVerification`, it means the email was sent from Firebase's system. Most likely it got caught either in some system along the way to your mailbox, or in the spam folder of your mailbox. Did you check the spam folder?